# c# System.InvalidCastException error while using SqlCommand and SqlDataReader

Tags: c#

I have some coordinate data with time and date. I just need some visualization with these float "GPMesafesi" and DateTime "Kislemsaat" on bitmap.

I need to convert DateTime to float in the second form. First coordinate's time must be origin and other data's time difference between origin

Lastly GPMesafesi will be x coordinate and Kislemsaat's difference between origin in the second form will be y coordinate. I need to reach 1 row at the same time in database but rows are sorted by order of use. if ı can reach index of te column in dataset or otherway it maybe works but ı cannot do right now.

But I got -System.InvalidCastException- error on
--while (reader.Read()) Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}",reader.GetFloat(0).ToString() + reader.GetSqlDateTime(0));--    that row. if someone can help it will be helpful.

excuses about bad speech

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyComputer\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=batu_deneme; Integrated Security=TRUE");
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
 void Render()
    {
   
        SqlCommand da1 = new SqlCommand("select GPMesafesi from TBL_GS_Koordinat_20210506  where kod= 2 and GüzergahNo= 1 and Kişlemsaat between '2021-05-06 06:07:13.000'and '2021-05-06 06:47:49.000'  order by GPMesafesi;"+"select Kişlemsaat from TBL_GS_Koordinat_20210506  where kod = 2 and GüzergahNo = 1 and Kişlemsaat between '2021-05-06 06:07:13.000'and '2021-05-06 06:47:49.000'  order by GPMesafesi", cs);
        cs.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = da1.ExecuteReader();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{0}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(0));
            while (reader.Read()) Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}",reader.GetFloat(0).ToString() + reader.GetSqlDateTime(0));
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
        reader.Close();
        cs.Close();
 using (var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height))
        using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))

        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black))

        {
            // draw one thousand random white lines on a dark blue background
            gfx.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            gfx.Clear(Color.White);

            
            
            
            var pt3 = new Point(0, 0);

            for(int i= 0; i<=500;i++)
            {

                //pen.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)rColor.Next(0, 255), (byte)rColor.Next(0, 255), (byte)rColor.Next(0, 255));


                var pt1 = pt3;
                var pt2 = new Point(x,y );
                pt3 = pt2;
                gfx.DrawLine(pen, pt1, pt2);

            }

            // copy the bitmap to the picturebox
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();
           


        }
}
```

Comment: should you be asking for different columns? you keep asking for column 0 (and indeed you're only asking for one column), but... presumably that column isn't a float *and* a date-time? did you intend to request multiple columns? is that "distance"? is it a float? a double? a decimal? (we don't know)

Comment: A side issue, but consider changing `pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();` to `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` (and then don't dispose `bmp`).

Comment: there is just 1 column in every query's result and lots of different rows (rows number can changeable but sorted by order of use). GPMesafe is sorted low to high and its just float that shows a car's travel distance on linear way. in database GPMesafesi is float and Kislemsaat is datetime. additionally that SqlDataReader code is not my original code.I found that on internet and tried to adapdate my code

Comment: `reader.GetFloat(0)` To be clear, `0` is **not** a row number. It is a **column** number.

Comment: but I prepared 2 query to get data .  I do not get range error.